# Writing/exporting files outside the Raspberry Pi home directory

Tags: export, files-and-directories, linux, raspberry-pi

When running *Mathematica* (v10) on my Raspberry Pi, I'd like to output an image file to a directory other than `/home/pi`.  I understand that letting *Mathematica* write files anywhere arbitrarily is a bad idea, but I'd like to be able to send it somewhere other than `/home/pi`.

Typically, if I want to write/move/copy a file somewhere I need the `sudo` command, but that does not appear to be an option with `Export`.

I assume the code should look like the following (to be sent to /dir1/dir2/dir3):

```
Export["/dir1/dir2/dir3/example.jpg", output, "jpg"]
```

but this returns an error:

> Export::nodir: Directory /home/pi/dir1/dir2/dir3/ does not exist
>
> Export:noopen: Cannot open /dir1/dir2/dir3/example.jpg.

What do I need to do to export my file to an arbitrary directory?

Comment: Assuming all the normal commands work on Pi, you can just do `SetDirectory["/dir1/dir2/dir3/"]` and then export normally using `Export["example.JPG", output]`. Does that work for you?

Comment: No, you don't need `SetDirectory`.  If you have permissions to write in the directory, and it exists, then you can write the file using an absolute path as in your example.  You should not be "typically" using sudo.  Create the directories you want and give them the permissions necessary outside of Mathematica to allow pi to write to them.

Comment: @MarkAdler So what permissions level is required for Mathematica to write to it?  chmod ---?

Comment: It depends on the owner of the directory.  If pi is the owner, then `chmod u+rwx dir`.  pi should be the owner for new directories you create for this purpose.  If necessary, `chown` can be used to set the owner.

Comment: If it is an existing directory in the system (which by the way means you probably should not be writing to it), then you would need to make sure its group is one of pi's, and then `chmod g+rwx dir`.

Comment: have you tried Export["\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\example.jpg", output, "jpg"]?

Comment: @Algohi Yes, that did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

Although this may not be the best answer, it seems to work for me.  Since I don't want to change the permissions of the existing directory to allow Mathematica to write to it, but I want to be able to have those files accessible from that directory, I am making a symbolic (soft) link between the directory in `/home/pi/` to the target directory by doing the following:

`sudo ln -s /home/pi/directory /dir1/dir2/dir3`

in order to link the contents of `/home/pi/directory` with `/dir1/dir2/dir3`.

I realize that this solution probably belongs in the Unix & Linux SE, but unless someone can come up with a way to do this within Mathematica without messing with permissions and risking security issues, this is what I'll be using.